# No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS

Tags: wireless, asus, iwlwifi, wifi-hardware-switch

I need some help.
I installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS and my WiFi doesn't work "No wifi adapter found".
Its a ASUS Vivobook.
thank you

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 11 Jan 2022 15:33 -03 -0300

Booted last: 11 Jan 2022 00:00 -03 -0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.11.0-44-generic #48~20.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 14 15:36:44 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:c821]
    Subsystem: AzureWave RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:3040]
    Kernel modules: rtw88_8821ce

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3529 IMC Networks Bluetooth Radio 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5a11 IMC Networks USB2.0 VGA UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 2717:ff80 Xiaomi Inc. Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 045e:07fd Microsoft Corp. Nano Transceiver 1.1
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

mac80211             1024000  2 rtw88_pci,rtw88_core
asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
cfg80211              888832  2 rtw88_core,mac80211
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
asus_wmi               36864  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
wmi                    32768  3 asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon
video                  53248  2 asus_wmi,i915

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.82/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3438sec preferred_lft 3438sec
    inet6 fe80::dd41:8e8a:bbda:6417/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.82 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         603       1  0 14:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Xiaomi Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Mi/Redmi series (RNDIS)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.11.0-44-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-2/1-2:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Conexão cabeada 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       7b159ce8-f7ad-36e2-adeb-1e2497775dcc
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.82/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1641929468
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = nadine-VivoBook-15-ASUS-Laptop-X540UAR
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.82
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::dd41:8e8a:bbda:6417/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   7b159ce8-f7ad-36e2-adeb-1e2497775dcc | Conexão cabeada 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: America/Sao_Paulo (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
depends:        cfg80211,libarc4
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-44-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.11.0-44-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.11.0-44-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[  325.670301] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[  927.862948] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device
[ 2949.069411] rndis_host 1-2:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-2, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF1]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: What script did you use to get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This post](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/installing-realtek-rtl8821ce-driver-to-use-the-wireless-network-interface-in-ubuntu/amp/) contains a guide to install the driver for your wifi adaptor.

Here is a summary of the main steps:

Install the required packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential dkms
```

Download the driver from GitHub and run the installation script:

```
git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce
cd rtl8821ce
chmod +x dkms-install.sh
sudo ./dkms-install.sh
```

Restart your system and the wifi should work.

If you need to uninstall it for some reason, return to that directory and run:

```
chmod +x dkms-remove.sh
sudo ./dkms-remove.sh
```

Comment: Perfect!!!! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

first blacklist rtw88_pci & rtw88_core

```
echo -e "blacklist rtw88_pci\n blacklist rtw88_core" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/ blaclist_rtw88.conf
```

Install the alternative driver-package from the official sources with ethernet or usb-tethering with your cellphone. You ned not any sourcecode from github.

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Reboot an check

```
lsmod | egrep 'cfg80|mac80'
iwconfig
iwlist chan
nmcli dev wifi list
```

Wifi is present and on? Try to connect.

Comment: I had no need to manually blacklist the two listed drivers. On my machine, by installing "rtl8221-dkms", dkms did automatically blacklist "rtw88_8821ce" instead.

Comment: Alternatively on top of that, utilize `apt download` command. It'll package it to `tar.gz` and you can then install the compressed `.deb` package with `sudo dpkg -i ./*.deb` if you are without network access but have a storage device instead.