# Asus Viobook Wifi connection not detected

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, asus

I recently bought a new Asus Viobook, and have it dual-booting with W10.  In Xubuntu, the wifi card is not active so I can only get online with a tethered mobile network.

I tried following the advice in [No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386578/no-wifi-adapter-found-asus) but it did not work, as git clone https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce requires a username and password, and "sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms" cannot be located.

Xubuntu knows the wifi card is there, it just cant use it.  Any help?

Thanks all.

Comment: Quite a few things "wrong" here. 1. How do you know the driver you want to install is suitable for your own hardware? Just because the linked question is about an ASUS laptop means nothing, yours can have a totally different wifi, even from a different manufacturer. 2. When dual-booting with Windows disabling its Fast Startup feature is a must as it can in some cases hijack devices. Assuming you actually have a Realtek RTL8821CE then yes, `rtl8821ce-dkms` is the correct driver and available at the Ubuntu repositories, no need for 3rd party's (...)

Comment: Hi ChanganAuto.  Thanks for helping!  Yes, you are right in that I should have looked into this in more detail first.  I was trying to solve the problem before bothering the community!

Comment: Lastly, the really not relevant - because no3 - issue with git. NO, it doesn't require username/password, so you did something wrong but again a moot point because you SHOULDN'T be following those answer even if you have the same device. Make sure your system is fully updated before try to install anything else and, of course, make sure all the official Ubuntu repositories (except "proposed" if there's no reason for it and there isn't) are selected before proceeding.

Comment: Thanks ChanganAuto.  I'll make sure to do that in future.

Answer (score -1):

So, I am an idiot.  Sorry to everyone!

I downloaded the .deb file from https://pkgs.org/download/rtl8821ce-dkms and was able to install the wifi drivers from there.

Comment: Again, **`rtl8821ce-dkms` is in the Ubuntu repositories. Do NOT use packages from 3rd parties if they already exist in the official repositories.