# My network card doesn't work well in Ubuntu

Tags: internet, asus

I have a little problem with my Asus F1400E, so basically when I try to install Ubuntu my network card doesn't work well, the connection is so unstable.

Im close to a router. I have installed W11 and with that OS doesn't have that problem. But i want to try Linux, I`m new to Ubuntu so if anyone could explain how to resolve the problem I would appreciate it very much. I try to install the solution that give this user of [this forum](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386578/no-wifi-adapter-found-asus). After this my connection was more stable but i can't get all the potential of my connection, so i left two captures of one connection test, one in Ubuntu and W11 to see the difference.
[image: 1]

Network: Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter driver:rtw_8821ce

The white one is from Linux and the black is from W11. I am im the exact same spot.

---

Network:
Device-1: Realtek RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
driver:rtw_8821ce

Comment: Sounds to me like a driver issue. The only thing that I can suggest is looking for the drivers specifically for that network card (probably Intel) from it's manufacturer's website. It may be hard to find the drivers for Linux.

Comment: Open a terminal and type `inxi -N`. Copy the output into your question (not the comments)

Comment: I have a 20.04 mini-pc that uses that device, and it works very well. https://i.imgur.com/YmTJx4C.png Download: 144.30 Mbit/s / Upload: 23.01 Mbit/s (speedtest-cli results) The only bad thing is that on this underpowered mini-pc it takes forever for DKMS to update the driver.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1353705/ubuntu-20-04-wifi-keeps-dropping/1353723#1353723 Check your MTU