# Wifi option is not available in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: wireless, 22.04, asus

I installed Ubuntu 22.04.4 but the wifi option is not available,
Laptop: Asus Vivobook 16X.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zsmVFbhPVn/

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 05 Mar 2024 21:48 EET +0200

Booted last: 05 Mar 2024 00:00 EET +0200

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

##### kernel ############################

Linux 6.5.0-21-generic #21~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Feb  9 13:32:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

0000:02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5520]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:5463 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04e8:6863 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:3579 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
wmi_bmof               12288  0
asus_wmi               73728  2 asus_nb_wmi,mfd_aaeon
ledtrig_audio          12288  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,asus_wmi
sparse_keymap          12288  1 asus_wmi
platform_profile       12288  1 asus_wmi
video                  73728  2 asus_wmi,i915
wmi                    40960  4 video,asus_wmi,wmi_bmof,mfd_aaeon

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.215.105/24 brd 192.168.215.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
       valid_lft 3466sec preferred_lft 3466sec
    inet6 fe80::fa52:7aaa:b1c5:346e/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.215.142 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> scope link metric 1000 
192.168.215.0/24 dev enx<IF from MAC [IF1]> proto kernel scope link src 192.168.215.105 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         587       1  0 21:45 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Galaxy series, misc. (tethering mode)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 6.5.0-21-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/net/enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.PATH:                           pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 1
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       4d5b5b8e-1663-3e27-a827-d4a11b44f581
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.PROMISC:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.215.105/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.215.142
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 192.168.215.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.215.142, mt = 100
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.215.142
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        broadcast_address = 192.168.215.255
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3599
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        dhcp_server_identifier = 192.168.215.142
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.215.142
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        expiry = 1709671596
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        host_name = farouk-ASUS
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        ip_address = 192.168.215.105
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        next_server = 192.168.215.142
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       routers = 192.168.215.142
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::fa52:7aaa:b1c5:346e/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 1024
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/2
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   4d5b5b8e-1663-3e27-a827-d4a11b44f581 | Wired connection 1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com./

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-31-mac-addr-change]
match-device=driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

'iw' is not installed (package "iw").

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>  Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    2.237686] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from usb0
[    2.251050] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: GuC firmware i915/adlp_guc_70.bin version 70.5.1
[    2.251054] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] GT0: HuC firmware i915/tgl_huc.bin version 7.9.3
[   26.386192] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-4, RNDIS device
[   54.137957] rndis_host 1-4:1.0 enx<IF from MAC [IF1]>: renamed from usb0

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: @user535733 https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zsmVFbhPVn/

Comment: `MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7902]`. Seems a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/763127/mt7902-driver-for-ubuntu . Sorry. Wired internet (ethernet or USB) will likely work. So will a cheap wi-fi dongle. Complain to Asus for using incompatible hardware -- they took your money.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No WIFI Adapter Found - ASUS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1386578/no-wifi-adapter-found-asus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer turned out to be incorrect. It seems that the reference I used is a false positive, and there is infact no support for the MT7902 in the kernel yet.

<s>The issue is that the WiFi chipset of your laptop is MEDIATEK Corp. Wi-Fi 6E `MT7902` Wireless Network Adapter. The driver for this adapter were added in the Linux `6.6` kernel series (as per https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=96859b01b7), while only the Linux `6.5` kernel series is available on 22.04.</s>

You have the option of installing the most recent kernels, built by ubuntu, as documented in https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds .

However, there may be issues if you have secure boot enabled, as the kernel packages from the mainline builds are usually unsigned (meaning that the secure-boot process will not recognize them as valid boot binaries). To make such a mainline kernel of series 6.6 or later, you will need to follow additional steps to sign the kernel on your laptop, as documented in https://ubuntu.com/blog/how-to-sign-things-for-secure-boot.

Comment: Though not yet finalized and supported in this site, Ubuntu 24.04  in development version (daily build) with the kernel 6.8 may work.

Comment: Ubuntu-built mainline packages are available for 6.8 even now: see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds and https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/ (though it's `6.8-RC8`; when `6.8` is released, the mainline build for it will be available soon after) whether or not it's the default kernel for `24.04`.

Comment: Note that the hardware probe is probably wrong and actually no recent kernel works. Same answer by @Samveen but see comments: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771748/417907

Comment: @usretc Updated the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: @Samveen I found your work (I think?) on github, but it seems it's not a workable option yet. I suppose you may or may not wish to advertise it. Good luck. I'm returning my Asus Vivobook 16X.